# Devise: Possible of moving change email (:confirmable) to a separate view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

Would it be possible to move the Devise email change a separate form? 
I would like to extract this functionality from my users#registrations page to a separate view.

I digged the devise wiki but was unable to find any reference.

Comment: What do you mean by **move the devise email change a separate form?**

Comment: account = registrations#edit account/notifications, account/password. I split my account stuff in multiple forms. And would like to have a separate page/view for the change password stuff and move it out of registrations/edit.html.erb

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to move the `change password` out of the `devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` and split this?

Comment: Hi @David yes that is correct. I tried before takes a lot of overruling and hacking the code it became mess. So asked for some thoughts on approach this time to attempt #2